# Get information from a json string?

Tags: c#, json

I have received a json string and i need help mapping that to an object

currently i am using:

```
string request = webClient.DownloadString(url);
```

which returns a json string of invoices:

```
"{\"invoices\":[
{\"url\":\"https://api.freeagent.com/v2/invoices/0000001\",\"contact\":\"https://api.freeagent.com/v2/contacts/000001\",\"dated_on\":\"2010-10-29\",\"due_on\":\"2010-11-28\",\"reference\":\"0001\",\"currency\":\"GBP\",\"exchange_rate\":\"1.0\",\"net_value\":\"60.0\",\"sales_tax_value\":\"68.0\",\"total_value\":\"528.0\",\"paid_value\":\"528.0\",\"due_value\":\"0.0\",\"status\":\"Paid\",\"omit_header\":false,\"payment_terms_in_days\":30,\"paid_on\":\"2011-11-14\"},{\"url\":\"https://api.freeagent.com/v2/invoices/0000002\",\"contact\":\"https://api.freeagent.com/v2/contacts/000002\",\"dated_on\":\"2010-11-19\",\"due_on\":\"2010-12-19\",\"reference\":\"0002\",\"currency\":\"GBP\",\"exchange_rate\":\"1.0\",\"net_value\":\"80.0\",\"sales_tax_value\":\"6.5\",\"total_value\":\"326.5\",\"paid_value\":\"650.0\",\"due_value\":\"76.5\",\"status\":\"Overdue\",\"comments\":\"Work\",\"omit_header\":false,\"payment_terms_in_days\":30}]}"
```

I have an invoice class:

```
public class Invoices
    {
        public string url { get; set; }
        public string project { get; set; } //--
        public string contact { get; set; } //--
        public string dated_on { get; set; } //--
        public string due_on { get; set; } //--
        public string paid_on { get; set; }
        public string reference { get; set; } //--
        public string currency { get; set; } //--
        public string exchange_rate { get; set; } //--
        public string net_value { get; set; }
        public string sales_tax_value { get; set; }
        public string total_value { get; set; }
        public string paid_value { get; set; }
        public string due_value { get; set; }
        public string discount_percent { get; set; } 
        public string status { get; set; }
        public string comments { get; set; } //--
        public string omit_header { get; set; }
        public string payment_terms_in_days { get; set; } //--
        public string ec_status { get; set; } //need to add fields
        public string written_off_date { get; set; }
}
```

Different invoices can return different information which is why there is a lot of values in the class that may not be in the json string.
I have tried these approaches but keep getting errors:

```
List<Invoices> list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Invoices>>(request);

Dictionary<string, string> values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(request);
```

Could someone show me how to get the information shown in the string out?

Edit:
I have also tried:

```
var info = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(request);
```

And that return this as a jObect

```
{
  "invoices": [
    {
      "url": "https://api.freeagent.com/v2/invoices/000000",
      "contact": "https://api.freeagent.com/v2/contacts/000000",
      "dated_on": "2010-10-29",
      "due_on": "2010-11-28",
      "reference": "0000",
      "currency": "GBP",
      "exchange_rate": "1.0",
      "net_value": "960.0",
      "sales_tax_value": "568.0",
      "total_value": "528.0",
      "paid_value": "528.0",
      "due_value": "0.0",
      "status": "Paid",
      "omit_header": false,
      "payment_terms_in_days": 30,
      "paid_on": "2011-11-14"
    },
    {
      "url": "https://api.freeagent.com/v2/invoices/000000",
      "contact": "https://api.freeagent.com/v2/contacts/000000",
      "dated_on": "2010-11-19",
      "due_on": "2010-12-19",
      "reference": "0000",
      "currency": "GBP",
      "exchange_rate": "1.0",
      "net_value": "980.0",
      "sales_tax_value": "46.5",
      "total_value": "326.5",
      "paid_value": "650.0",
      "due_value": "76.5",
      "status": "Overdue",
      "comments": "Work",
      "omit_header": false,
      "payment_terms_in_days": 30
    }
}
```

Comment: The JSON is not an array - it is an object which has a root property called "invoices" which is the actual array of invoices. It doesn't look like you're taking this property into account. You can always serialize your class to see what its JSON will look like.

Comment: I have also tried:     var info = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(request);
    However I could not work out what to do with that?

Comment: i'll make an edit to show the results of that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classes (as for the Json u posted) should look like this:

```
public class Invoice
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string contact { get; set; }
    public string dated_on { get; set; }
    public string due_on { get; set; }
    public string reference { get; set; }
    public string currency { get; set; }
    public string exchange_rate { get; set; }
    public string net_value { get; set; }
    public string sales_tax_value { get; set; }
    public string total_value { get; set; }
    public string paid_value { get; set; }
    public string due_value { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public bool omit_header { get; set; }
    public int payment_terms_in_days { get; set; }
    public string paid_on { get; set; }
    public string comments { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Invoice> invoices { get; set; }
}
```

And:

```
RootObject list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(request);
```

The RootObject object contains a list of invoices

Json: (there is a `]` missing on your version, near the end of the Json to close the array)

```
{
"invoices": [
    {
      "url": "https://api.freeagent.com/v2/invoices/000000",
      "contact": "https://api.freeagent.com/v2/contacts/000000",
      "dated_on": "2010-10-29",
      "due_on": "2010-11-28",
      "reference": "0000",
      "currency": "GBP",
      "exchange_rate": "1.0",
      "net_value": "960.0",
      "sales_tax_value": "568.0",
      "total_value": "528.0",
      "paid_value": "528.0",
      "due_value": "0.0",
      "status": "Paid",
      "omit_header": false,
      "payment_terms_in_days": 30,
      "paid_on": "2011-11-14"
    },
    {
      "url": "https://api.freeagent.com/v2/invoices/000000",
      "contact": "https://api.freeagent.com/v2/contacts/000000",
      "dated_on": "2010-11-19",
      "due_on": "2010-12-19",
      "reference": "0000",
      "currency": "GBP",
      "exchange_rate": "1.0",
      "net_value": "980.0",
      "sales_tax_value": "46.5",
      "total_value": "326.5",
      "paid_value": "650.0",
      "due_value": "76.5",
      "status": "Overdue",
      "comments": "Work",
      "omit_header": false,
      "payment_terms_in_days": 30
    }]
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your help however this is throwing an exception: An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll but was not handled in user code ------ Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object because the type requires a JSON array

Comment: Could it be that this is added to the front of the string: "{\"invoices\":[ ?

Comment: @BrianPeach i edited there is a ] missing in your Json. U never close the array.

Comment: Sorry that would have been a typo from me copying it accross as it returns a few more than 2 items and I didnt want to clog up my question

Comment: @BrianPeach Could u post the request url?

Comment: It wont let me post it as its "too long by 11316 characters" however the first one i showed should be closed, or assume its closed

is it possible to convert the object to a json array as it says?

Comment: @BrianPeach Actually i updated again sorry for that try `RootObject list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(request);` as the invoices are not an array itself the Rootobject will contains the list already

Comment: That is it, you have solved it. Thanks a lot for your help and for being patient :)

Comment: What about missing fields in json ?

Comment: Ignore my comment. it puts null there.

Answer (score 1):

> Could someone show me how to get the information shown in the string
>   out?

You can do this (dynamic):

```
   JavaScriptSerializer oSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
   dynamic lst  = oSerializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(request );
   Console.WriteLine(lst["invoices"][0]["due_on"]); <--put here whatever you want.
```

Here for example , I read the value of the first item in array :

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help this seems to be working, so how would i for example map this to the class shown above?
I'm getting stuck with it having a key of "invoices" and a value of X objects then each object having an inner key/value

Comment: If the structure is dynamic - the only way (IMO) is via reflection. don't go there. just build a map table where you can recognize a structure via a unique field. for example : Structure 1 contains MyInput1. (which is not found in other structures). that way - you could map each strucuture to a class  . Feel free to ask further questions.

Comment: Well with each invoice holding a different set of value, I dont think i can do that for example the class above holds all that info. By doing this dymanically I cannot seem to get the info out, would there be any other way? maybe could try removing the "invoices" key with sting.replace then try mapping?